# Laptop screen too dark

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

Laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad E540) screen is too dark. You can see a little if you use external light directly on screen and it's working properly with an external monitor.

I had two Thinkpad E540:

1. A - Didn't use it, screen working properly, nothing broken but slow, small RAM and HDD.
2. B - Broken plastic body and keyboard, problem with too dark screen

I put motherboard with CPU, GPU, RAM and HDD from B to A plus heatsink fan from B as A doesn't have dedicated GPU. (The fan is quite overheating, in need of change)

Then I did Factory recovery but the problem with too dark screen stayed the same.

I don't really know what could be the problem (maybe GPU?) so I will take the laptopt to repair shop, but that has to wait at least month. For now any idea?

Comment: check in the BIOS for automatic dimming and switch it off. Change brightness to max.

Comment: Hard to tell from what you wrote, but it seems that the back-light in the LCD panel is off or broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following troubleshoot way:

It seems that it is not good to judge whether there is a problem with the screen of B from our operation.

Try to remove A's screen and install it on B:

If the display is normal, there is a problem with the screen of B.
If it is also very dark, then there is no problem with the screen of B.

If there is a problem with the screen of B, and the settings have not been changed, it is likely that the backlight LED of the screen is broken or the screen line is broken.

If there is no problem with the screen of B, there may be a problem with the parts on the motherboard of B.
We can refresh the BIOS and see if the screen is normal (this operation may need to be performed by the repair center). If the problem persists, it is a hardware problem outside the screen, most likely the GPU.